Redis take much time to retrieve data
I am working on node.js project. I start using Redis for cache data by upstash. and it needs more time to retrieve data then without redis. when I am using redis.get() or redis.set() it needs too much time.
const Redis = require('ioredis')
const redis = new Redis(REDIS_URL);

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {

        const redisProduct = await redis.get('products');
        if(redisProduct) {
            console.log("returned from redis")
            const products = JSON.parse(redisProduct)
            return res.render('products', { products })
        }
        const products = await productSchema.aggregate([
            {
                $sort: { createdAt: -1 }
            }
        ])
        await redis.set('products', JSON.stringify(products), 'EX', 300)
        console.log('quaried from database and set to the redis')
        return res.render('products', { products })
    } catch(error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error)
        res.status(404).send('Something went wrong')
    }
})


What is the issue you are having?

When I use redis, it takes about 500ms to retrieve the data but without redis it needs 50ms. I do not want to retrieve data from database all the time, I want to add some caching. The abundance of data does not slow down the speed cause I have a little amount of data, just two little object

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

500 ms is half a second, that's extremely fast. Your db query without caching is only so fast because you are still setting up and have not acquired a large amount of data to query. If you know you will never have a large amount of data you do not need a caching service. I am pretty sure this is how it is all intended to work. Hope that is helpful to you.
